# Сериализация объектов класса

Tags: java

Прохожу один курс по Java. Есть задание на котором застрял уже второй день. Задание:

Дан сериализуемый класс `Animal`:

```
class Animal implements Serializable {
    private final String name;

    public Animal(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (obj instanceof Animal) {
            return Objects.equals(name, ((Animal) obj).name);
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Реализуйте метод, который из переданного массива байт восстановит массив объектов `Animal`. Массив байт устроен следующим образом. Сначала идет число типа `int`, записанное при помощи `ObjectOutputStream.writeInt(size)`. Далее подряд записано указанное количество объектов типа `Animal`, сериализованных при помощи `ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(animal)`.

Если вдруг массив байт не является корректным представлением массива экземпляров `Animal`, то метод должен бросить исключение `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException`.

Причины некорректности могут быть разные. Попробуйте подать на вход методу разные некорректные данные и посмотрите, какие исключения будут возникать. Вот их-то и нужно превратить в `IllegalArgumentException` и выбросить. Если что-то забудете, то проверяющая система подскажет. Главное не глотать никаких исключений, т.е. не оставлять нигде пустой catch.

Мой вариант решения:

```
//импорт необходимых библиотек
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Objects;

//сериализуемый класс
public class Animal implements Serializable{

    private final String name;

    public Animal(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (obj instanceof Animal) {
            return Objects.equals(name, ((Animal) obj).name);
        }
        return false;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        //создание экземпляра класса с объектами dog, cow, cat, rabbit
        Animal [] animals = new Animal[]{new Animal("dog"),new Animal("cow"),new Animal("cat"),new Animal("rabbit")};
       //открываем поток вывода данных
        ByteArrayOutputStream os = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(os);
       //записываем в поток количество объектов в классе
        oos.writeInt(4);

        //Записываем объекты в поток вывода
        for (Animal animal1 : animals)
        {
            oos.writeObject(animal1);
        }
        //закрываем поток
       oos.close();

        //восстанавливаем из потока объекты класса
        byte[] bArray = os.toByteArray();
        Animal[] animal2 = deserializeAnimalArray(bArray);
        System.out.println (animal2.toString());//печатаем в консоль
    }

    //метод десериализации объектов класса
       public static Animal[] deserializeAnimalArray(byte[] data)  {
               try(ObjectInputStream in = new ObjectInputStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(data))) {//открываем поток ввода байт
                     int x = in.readInt();//читаем из потока кол-во объектов в классе
                     Animal[] animal3  = new Animal[x];//создаем массив объектов

                    if(x >= 0) {//проверяем что-бы число объектов было положительно
                              for (int i = 0; i <= x; i++) {
                                    animal3 = (Animal[]) in.readObject();//заполняем массив объектами
                                   }

                          }

                    in.close();//закрываем поток ввода
                    return animal3;//возвращаем массив объектов
                 } catch (IOException e){//ловим и бросаем исключения
                    throw new IllegalArgumentException(e);
               }catch (ClassNotFoundException e){
                   throw new IllegalArgumentException(e);
              }
    }
}
```

ИДЕ постоянно бросает ошибки

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: Animal cannot
>   be cast to [LAnimal;  at
>   Animal.deserializeAnimalArray(Animals.java:68)    at
>   Animal.main(Animals.java:57)

Кто-то может направить на правильный путь?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Во-первых, вот в этой строчке творится непонятно что:

```
animal3 = (Animal[]) in.readObject()
```

Вы (по заданию) должны считать объект типа `Animal` и добавить его в массив `animal3`, то есть должно быть так:

```
animal3[i] = (Animal) in.readObject()
```

Во-вторых, Вы считываете на один объект больше, чем есть на самом деле. Замените Ваш:

```
for (int i = 0; i <= x; i++)
```

на

```
for (int i = 0; i < x; i++)
```

Comment: Спасибо. Все действительно так, большое спасибо за помощь.